# I am not getting text macro completion in latest xcode (3.2.1)

Tags: xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, macos

I recently upgraded my machine from Leopard to Snow Leopard. Also I installed the latest Xcode 3.2.1 for Snow Leopard.

Currently I am not getting code completion for built-in macros. For example 'if' followed by ESC gives completion list with #IF and ifstream. However I can insert it from menu Edit>Insert Text macro>C>If Block.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for it. Deleting the "/Users/name/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared" made it work perfectly.

Actually, while working with the previous versions of Xcode, I tried adding custom completion macros to "Shared/Xcode/Specifications". But the xcode 3.2.1 appeared to be  messed with custom and default specification and failed to display the completions.

Answer (score 1):

Text macro completions are context-sensitive.  Are you sure you're in a C file, and that an if block is valid at the point you're typing in? You should be seeing something like this, even without pressing Esc:
[alt text http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/If.png](http://idisk.mac.com/cdespinosa/Public/If.png)

Comment: Yes. It is a C file. But I found the the real problem and answering it. Thanks for the reply.